# Issue with Vaadin Coding

Tags: vaadin

Unable to use the EDIT option to edit each row in a table, i am using SQLContainer. Need help in writing the exact code to edit the values.How to create edit button to each row??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please provide the code you have, will be much easier to so where you made a wrong turn

Comment: Have you read the Book Of Vaadin [chapter on SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.html)? Have you read the [SQLContainer Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/tutorial/sql)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ColumnGenerator,

See the [book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html) section 5.14.5 to learn how to add a ColumnGenerator to a table.

Regards

Éric

Comment: Hi Eric, I have already generated the columns required and even added a button to it. But when ever i am clicking on the button, the event is returning a NULL.